# how to transfer data from html in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I want to transfer data from my html to JS file...
It's works with AngularJS+Onsen+PhoneGap

This is my HTML file

```
<ons-col class="action-col" ng-click="openSocialSharing('qqqq {{phone.adress_lat}} wwwww')">
    <div class="action-icon"><ons-icon  icon="ion-loading-c" spin="true"></ons-icon></div>
    <div class="action-label">Share</div>
</ons-col>
```

This is my JS file

```
$scope.openSocialSharing = function(qqrq){
   console.log('DATA- '+qqrq); 
   window.plugins.socialsharing.share(qqrq);
}
```

And console result

> 01-05 13:43:41.760: I/chromium(17719): [INFO:CONSOLE(197)] "DATA -
>   qqqq wwwww", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js (197)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send data from html to angular function just send object field name like this

```
ng-click="openSocialSharing(phone.adress_lat)"
```